# Users/Friends with twitterizer that don't follow back

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

I am using twitterizer in an ASP.NET-project. I nned an example (code) how I can use twitterizer to show a list of followers (paged) for a special account that don't follow back.

The query is: Give me all users that I follow for e.g. 5 days but that didn't follow me back. The result should be displayed in a GridView with paging.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to get a list of friends - ok. But the friends are all people I follow, right? But I want to see since when I am following the users and only the friends that don't follow me

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the email, there is no way to filter friends or followers by date.

Your best bet to do this is to use `TwitterFriendship.FriendsIds()` and `TwitterFriendship.FollowersIds()`, then select the difference between the two. That will give you the list of followers that you don't follow. (Friends are users you follow.) In order to identify new friends/followers, you'll need to keep a list of the Ids, then consult that list at a later date to see the changes over time.

Comment: ok thanks. Perhaps the new site-streams offer such features cause in the API there is not time-stamp when a friedship is made. Does twitterizer offer access to site-streams?

Comment: Streaming isn't completed in Twitterizer yet, but it is the current top priority (with the exception of bug fixes).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a database (or list, etc) of users you followed and users who follow you. Update this as often you you need and add a time stamp for each new addition. Then you could query this database to create the list you want.